# How do I get multiple values unpacked in C++ vectors

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, std, stdvector

I have this function that returns colors in RGB format for me from here

```
std::vector<cv::Vec3b> colors = find_dominant_colors(matImage, count);
```

but now along with that I also want the image that the function `find_dominant_colors` generates to return so that I can use it. It generates three images that I write using `cv::imwrite` but I want those three images to be returned to the function call so that I can further view it directly when it is returned instead of fetching the directory for it.

How do I unpack multiple values in that line of code like get the image as well as color instead of just color. Do I have to use multiple vectors? How do I do that ? 
The vector used here is a opencv vector to get RGB values from an image.

EDIT :

```
    std::vector<cv::Vec3b> find_dominant_colors(cv::Mat img, int count) {
    const int width = img.cols;
    const int height = img.rows;
    std::vector<cv::Vec3b> colors = get_dominant_colors(root);

    cv::Mat quantized = get_quantized_image(classes, root);
    cv::Mat viewable = get_viewable_image(classes);
    cv::Mat dom = get_dominant_palette(colors);

    cv::imwrite("./classification.png", viewable);
    cv::imwrite("./quantized.png", quantized);
    cv::imwrite("./palette.png", dom);

    return colors;
}
```

Above function returns colors to here

```
std::vector<cv::Vec3b> colors = find_dominant_colors(matImage, count);
```

I also want it to return `viewable quantized dom` , how do I do that?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're asking for.

Comment: you can only return one value from a function, but you can write a `struct` with as many members as you like

Comment: Please add more details, currently the quesiton is rather unclear. What do you want to get from the function?

Comment: @Qix   The code returns the value colors after it processes the image. Now I also want it to return the image along with color value but as the returned color is unpacked into opencv vector how do I define another vector that will get me the image along with it in the same function call.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I have added more details in the comment above.

Comment: @AshwinPhadke Describing code with words just makes this more confusing. Show code for what you want, and show what the types involved are.

Comment: sry when I said "details" i meant code. As super says, understanding code given only a description in words is extremely hard. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: added more info as edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function

```
std::vector<cv::Vec3b> colors = find_dominant_colors(matImage, count);
```

and now you want to change the function to return "more", then you can declare a data structure

```
struct find_dominant_colors_result {
    std::vector<cv::Vec3b> colors;
    cv::Mat quantized;
    cv::Mat viewable;
    cv::Mat dom;
};
```

Now the call would look like this:

```
find_dominant_colors_result x = find_dominant_colors(matImage, count);
```

or rather

```
auto x = find_dominant_colors(matImage, count);
```

while you would have to modify the function to

```
find_dominant_colors_result find_dominant_colors(cv::Mat img, int count) {
    find_dominant_color_result result;
    const int width = img.cols;
    const int height = img.rows;
    result.colors = get_dominant_colors(root);

    result.quantized = get_quantized_image(classes, root);
    result.viewable = get_viewable_image(classes);
    result.dom = get_dominant_palette(result.colors);

    cv::imwrite("./classification.png", result.viewable);
    cv::imwrite("./quantized.png", result.quantized);
    cv::imwrite("./palette.png", result.dom);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: ` 
conversion from ‘std::vector<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3> >’ to non-scalar type ‘find_dominant_colors_result’ requested
  333 |     find_dominant_colors_result x = find_dominant_colors(matImage, count);
   `

Comment: @AshwinPhadke of course you have to adjust more than just the function call. You also have to adjust the function

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Define your `find_dominant_colors` function to return a `std::tuple<cv::Mat, cv::Mat, cv::Mat, cv::Vec3b>`, and do this in the `return` statement:

```
return std::make_tuple(quantized, viewable, dom, colors);
```

In C++17, you can make use of [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to handle the returned values in a convenient way:

```
auto [quantized, viewable, dom, colors] = find_dominant_colors(matImage, count);
```

If you don't have C++17, use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to handle the returned `std::tuple`:

```
cv::Mat quantized;
cv::Mat viewable;
cv::Mat dom;
cv::Vec3b colors;

std::tie(quantized, viewable, dom, colors) = find_dominant_colors(matImage, count);
```

Or you can let type deduction work for you, and use [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) to access the members of the returned `std::tuple`:

```
auto values = find_dominant_colors(matImage, count);
auto quantized = std::get<0>(values);
auto viewable = std::get<1>(values);
auto dom = std::get<2>(values);
auto colors = std::get<3>(values);
```

Comment: Preferred over defining a new data structure. :-)

Comment: @Gupta basically this is declaring a new data structure, the main difference is that you cannot give custom names to tuples elements, and of course structured bindings are nice to have when you can use C++17, its a tradeoff

Comment: @Gnawme   I am getting type conversion errors, how do I handle returned values if not using C++17? . I tried declaring as individual variable too but it didn't work.

Comment: I expanded my answer for non-C++17, hope it helps.

Comment: @Gnawme Prior to checking your edit here I used std::tie in the order the arguments are returned by the function and similarly declaring them in main, and yet the error persists. Does it have something to do with defining the function they way I have defined as in `std::tuple<cv::Mat, cv::Mat, cv::Mat, cv::Vec3b> find_dominant_colors(cv::Mat img, int count) {
code }`

Comment: @AshwinPhadke I expanded my answer to use `std::get` and `auto`, which should get around the type conversion issues (`std::tie` actually ends up with a tuple of references).